# Custom login.php template in Concrete5 page

Tags: php, forms, concrete5

I want to port a website to Concrete5. I now have the problem that I can't modify the layout of the login page, I managed to replace the template but every time I add my own form, it won't show (or it blinks and disappears).

How do I modify the code of login.php to show my custom login form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the login page via 'single pages' within your theme package. This [guide](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/overriding-single-pages-within-a-package-theme/) gives a great overview of how to do it.